# Powershell regex to add white space after line so character count equals 15

Tags: regex, powershell

Could I use a regular expression in Powershell to add white spaces after items in an array so the character length of each item equals 15?

```
Dog[12 spaces]
Tiger[10 spaces]
Elephant[7 spaces]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `PadRight` method:

```
"Dog".PadRight(15, ' ')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also use format strings, use positive numbers to pad letf:

```
'{0,-15}' -f 'dog'
```